# Unable to use InputBox in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, inputbox

I added a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll to my Silverlight project, then I tried using

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Question?", "Title", "Default Text");
```

as suggested in several places, but I get an error (13) saying that

> 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction' does not contain a definition for 'InputBox'

The intellisense only lists: `Choose, IIf, Partition` and `Switch`.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: Wrong kind of project.  You can't get a 10 second download for the Silverlight runtime with stuff like this included.  Just make your own.

Comment: [`Interaction.InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: That's a good point, Hans.  I hadn't really thought about that aspect of it.  I was just hoping for a quick, modal box I could pop up with a line or two of code.  I ended up following your advice and making my own, but I wasn't too happy that it was the only solution.

Comment: None of the places I found on the Internet that talk about using InputBox in C# mentioned that it wasn't available in Silverlight. Hopefully this question and the comments will save some time for others in the future.  Thanks to both of you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample code for inputbox in silverlight

```
string question = system.windows.browser.htmlpage.window.invoke("prompt", new string[] {
    "What is your name?",
    ""
}) as string;
```